# Creating directories based off variable names

Tags: c

I have been creating a C program that is going to pull a range of data from excel and store it in variables. My question, how do i create a directory in C that uses variables. I have tried several ways yesterday while at work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //creating directory (works)
    system("md E:\sub_directory");
    system("mkdir E:\\sub_dir2");

    //trying to create directory based off variables (not working yet)
    char CustName[50] = "Mars";
    char Product[50] = "Chocolate Drops";
    int JobNumber = 100;

    system("md E:\\",JobNumber,CustName,Product"",JobNumber,CustName,Product);
system("md E:\\%04i %s %s",JobNumber,CustName,Product);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see above, this is the code that i finished up with. The first section was just a reference point so i know base command structure. I then proceeded to fiddle with formatting that i currently know which didnt work.

Would anyone be able to shed some light on how i would use variables name to create the directories? (im currently working on a windows 10 machine but the program is going to be run on a windows 7 machine. I dont know if this changes anything.

Comment: Read up on `sprintf`.

Comment: You don't have to use system() you can use  mkdir(path);

Answer (score 3):

You should use `sprintf` to create one string with the complete pathname you want to create. Then you should use the `mkdir` function of the standard library to create the directory.

Note that to create a directory, all component paths must exist, so to create `E:\my\path` you may first need to create `E:\my` and then `E:\my\path`.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a look at `sprintf` and i think i understand it. i have the following code:

```
char CustName[50] = "Mars";
char Product[50] = "Chocolate Drops";
int JobNumber = 100;
char *filepath[100];

sprintf(*filepath, "mkdir D:\\%04i %s %s", JobNumber, CustName, Product);
puts(*filepath);
```

sorry if this isnt the correct use, i am still pritty new to programming

Comment: I don't know how much use it would be to you but you can also turn variable names into strings by using # in Macro functions.

Comment: You should write: `sprintf(filepath, "D:\\%04i\\%s\\%s", JobNumber, CustName, Product);` and then call `mkdir(filepath);`